# Smooth Enlargement of the domain of convex functions:

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f : \Bbb{R^n}  \to \Bbb{R} \cup \{ +\infty \} $ be  a convex function, then the domain of $f$ is the convex set $ D= \{ x \in \Bbb{R^n} ~ |\quad f(x) < \infty \}.$

Questions:

$1)$ Can we find a convex  function $g: \Bbb{R^n}  \to \Bbb{R} \cup \{ +\infty \} $ such that $g=f$ on $D$ and the domain of $g$ has nonempty interior ?

$2)$ In above question can we additionally assume for all $ x \in
 \text{int[ }
\text{Domain} (g) ]\setminus D $
$g$ is differentiable at $ x $ ?

As an example Take  $$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 |x| & (x,y) \in \Bbb{R} \times \{ 0 \}  \\ 
  +\infty &    O.W
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then one can take $g(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 } $.

P.S: Question $1$ geometrically is clear since we can extend $f$ along $ D^{\bot} $.

Basically I am interested the  answer for locally convex space $X$, however I think the answer of the question $2$ even is not clear in $\Bbb {R^n} $.

Comment: Is $g$ required to agree with $f$ on $D$?

Comment: Yes,  $g$  is an extension of $f$  I'll correct it, thanks @littleO

Comment: Your first sentence is strange. It seems that $f$ has two domains.

Comment: @zhw. can you tell me why it looks $f$ has two domain? it seems clear.

Comment: Well you have $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$ to start with, and then you have $D.$

Comment: @zhw Note that for functions  $f : \Bbb{R^n}  \to \Bbb{R} \cup \{ +\infty \}$  Domain is not considered whole $R^n$. it is indeed the set where $f$ gets finite values. (as I defined in question ).

Comment: @zhw This strange use of the word "domain" is common in convex optimization, unfortunately. Really, $D =\{x\mid f(x)<\infty\}$ should be called the "effective domain" of $f$, not the "domain" of $f$.  But frequently in this field people omit the word "effective".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes. The support $D$ of $f$ is a convex set. Let ${\rm aff}(D)$ be its [affine hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull). Then, ${\rm aff}(D)=x_0+U$ for a linear subspace $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and any $x_0\in {\rm aff}(D)$. Let $V$ be a complementary subspace, so $\mathbb R^n=U\oplus V$.

Starting with the first question, define $g$ on $D+V$ by $g(x+v)=f(x)$ for any $x\in D$ and $v\in V$, and set $g$ to be $\infty$ elsewhere. This is convex with support $D+V$, which has nonempty interior ${\rm relint}(D)+V$ (${\rm relint}(D)$ is the [relative interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior)).

For the second question, choose a nonnegative smooth function $\theta\colon U\to\mathbb R$ with support in the interior of the unit ball, symmetric so that $\theta(u)=\theta(-u)$ and with unit integral $\int_U\theta(u)\,du=1$. Let $D_g$ consist of the points $x+v\in D+V$ such that the closed ball of radius $\lVert v\rVert$ in $U$ entered at $x$ is contained in $D$. This contains $D$ and has interior containing ${\rm relint}(D)$. Define $g\colon D_g\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
g(x+v)= \int_U f(x+\lVert v\rVert z)\theta(z)\,dz,
$$
with $\int_U\,\cdot\,dz$ denoting the standard Lebesgue integral on $U$.
Then, $g$ is smooth on $D_g\setminus D$. For $x+v,y+w\in D_g$ and $p,q\ge0$ with $p+q=1$,
\begin{align}
pg(x+v)+qg(y+w)&=\int_U\left(pf(x+\lVert v\rVert z)+qf(y+\lVert w\rVert z)\right)\theta(z)\,dz\\
&\ge\int_Uf(px+qy+(p\lVert v\rVert+q\lVert w\rVert) z)\theta(z)\,dz
\end{align}
Using the inequality $p\lVert v\rVert+q\lVert w\rVert\ge\lVert pv+qw\rVert$ and the fact that convexity of $f$ implies that $\int_Uf(x+tz)\theta(z)\,dz$ is increasing in $t$ to get
$$
pg(x+v)+qg(y+w)\ge g(px+qy+pv+qw).
$$
So, $g$ is convex. Entend to all of $\mathbb R^n$ by setting $g(x)=\infty$ outside of $D_g$.

---

I'll clarify a few properties which have been asked in the comments:

**Convexity of $D_g$**: Suppose that $x,y\in D$ and $v,w\in V$ are such that $x+v,y+w\in D_g$. For $p,q > 0$, $p+q=1$, we need to show that $z+u\in D_g$ where $z=px+qy$ and $u=pv+qw$. We have $\lVert u\rVert\le p\lVert v\rVert+q\lVert w\rVert$. By definition of $D_g$, we need to show that if $a$ is in the closed ball of radius $\lVert u\rVert$ about 0 in $U$ then $z+a\in D$. Setting
$$
b = \frac{\lVert v\rVert}{p\lVert v\rVert+q\lVert w\rVert}a,\
c = \frac{\lVert w\rVert}{p\lVert v\rVert+q\lVert w\rVert}a,
$$
then $\lVert b\rVert\le\lVert v\rVert$ and $\lVert c\rVert \le \lVert w\rVert$. So, $x+b,y+c\in D$ and, by convexity of $D$,
$$
z+a=px+qy+pb+qc=p(x+b)+q(y+c)\in D
$$
*QED*

**$g$ is differentiable on $D_g\setminus D$**: Rearranging the definition of $g$,
$$
g(x+v)=\int_Uf(z)\lVert v\rVert^{-d}\theta((z-x)/\lVert v\rVert)\,dz
$$
where $d$ is the dimension of $U$. You now only need to use that $\lVert v\rVert^{-d}\theta((z-x)/\lVert v\rVert)$ is differentiable over $v\not=0$. *QED*

**$\int_Uf(x+tz)\theta(z)\,dz$ is increasing in $t\ge0$**: using the symmetry of $\theta$,
$$
\int_Uf(x+tz)\theta(z)\,dz=\frac12\int_U\left(f(x+tz)+f(x-tz)\right)\theta(z)\,dz
$$
As $\theta$ is non-negative, it only needs to be shown that $t\mapsto f(x+tz)+f(x-tz)$ is increasing in $t$. In fact, using convexity of $f$, this is convex and symmetric in $t$. *QED*

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed was amazing proof (+1). Could you plz Just clarify several things in your solution. Part one is clear, I also expected same argument of for part one.  In part 2.

\\

1- Why is $D_g$  convex set?

2-  In $ \int_U f(x+\lVert v\rVert z)\theta(z)\,dz,$ shouldn't we replace $U$ by the Unit Ball in $U$ to avoid $f$ gets $+ \infty$ value.

3- Why is $g$  differentiable on $D_g  \setminus D$ ?


4-Why is  $\int_Uf(x+tz)\theta(z)\,dz$  increasing  function  in $t$, for example take $f(t) = - \ln t$ on $D= (0, + \infty)$

Comment: In $\int_U\cdot\,\theta(z)\,dz$ you can replace the domain of integration by the unit ball in $U$ if you like, as $\theta$ is zero outside of this range (o.k., you need the convention that $\infty 0=0$, but that is standard). For your other questions, I'll answer them in my post.

Comment: Thanks.  I am actually interested same result in Banach spaces. I think your approach can be extended to Hilbert spaces, but not banach or even reflexive, Am I right?

Even in Hilbert space there we don't know if ${\rm relint}(D) \neq \emptyset $   .

Comment: I don't think the result will hold in Hilbert spaces, and you need not have ${\rm relint}(D)\not=\emptyset$.

Comment: I'm quite positive that result holds in infinite dimension, I 'd seen a paper where something even stronger than this extension,  holds in reflexive space , with more assumptions though, the proof employed infimal convolution.

Comment: Why can't your proof be adopted to Hilbert spaces? Where is problem? Is it  the existence of the bump function ?

Comment: In infinite dimensions it is no longer true that convex sets have nonempty relative interior, and there is no Lebesgue measure to integrate with respect to. I also think that in infinite dimensions, properties such as continuity need to be stated more explicitly (convex functions need not be continuous) in order to get a good result.

Comment: Consider the case where $D\subset\ell^2$ is the open unit ball of $\ell^1\subset\ell^2$ and $f(x)=(1-\lVert x\rVert_1)^{-1}$ on $D$. I don't think that this will extend to a convex function on any subset of $\ell^2$ with nonempty interior.

Comment: one question if $f$ is already differentiable (restricted on its domain) does this domain enlargement preserve the differentiability of $f$ on new bigger domain?